# cant stream from youtube

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, iostream

Im trying to stream a video from youtube when the user select a row in my tableview,
heres the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{          

  NSString *videoURLString = [self.listaVideos objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURLString];

        self.theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:[self.theMovie moviePlayer]];

        [self.view addSubview:self.theMovie.view];
        [self.theMovie setWantsFullScreenLayout:NO];
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
        [[self.theMovie moviePlayer] play];
}



-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"ENded");
}
```

And the error: `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MPMoviePlayerViewController: 0x7a256a0>.`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
    [self.view addSubview:self.theMovie.view];
```

You appear to be adding it the view, then presenting it. (If you don't want to present it, remove that line instead)

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` can't stream YouTube videos.

Oh, also what Amit Shah said as well (removing the `addSubview:` will take care of the unbalanced calls, but not the inability to play videos).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which the video from youtube url.If you are really looking for streaming the Video from Youtube then, rely on below code it's very easy & event you don't have to take much care of Event Handling , buffering etc...

```
@interface VideoPlayerContrl : UIViewController {

        IBOutlet UIWebView *youtubeVideo;

}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head>\n"
    "<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head>\n"
    "<body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">\n"
    "<div><object width=\"212\" height=\"172\">\n"
    "<param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param>\n"
    "<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>\n"
    "<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"\n"
    "type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"247\" height=\"178\"></embed>\n"
    "</object></div></body></html>\n";

    [youtubeVideo loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/adplayer/colgate.mp4"]];

}
```

Hope that would have solved your problem :)